# DB2 date conversion

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 `INTEGER` columns like the following:

```
Month      Year
-----      -----
  5         2011
```

Is there any way to convert that to a single column `VARCHAR` like this: `May-2011`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to do this since you don't have a date object (ie its not like youre finding the month of a timestamp), you can use a case statement but it gets long.

```
SELECT CASE Month
            WHEN '1' THEN 'January'
            WHEN '2' THEN 'February'
            WHEN '3' THEN 'March'
            WHEN '4' THEN 'April'
            ...
      END+'-'+Year
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME(
  DATE(CAST(Year AS CHAR(4)) || '-' || TRIM(CAST(Month AS CHAR(2))) || '-1')
) || '-' || CAST(Year AS CHAR(4))
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, assuming that the columns `Month` and `Year` are integers and Month has the domain 1-12:

```
select   substring('---JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3*Month , 3 )
       + '-'
       + right(digits(Year),4)
from some_table
```

If `Month` is 0 you'll get '---' as the month; if it's less than 0 or greater than 12, you'll get some sort of blooey.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to convert the month value, like this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION INT2MONTH (MONTH INTEGER)
     RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
     LANGUAGE SQL
     CONTAINS SQL
     NO EXTERNAL ACTION
     DETERMINISTIC
     RETURN MONTHNAME('2000-' || RIGHT('0' || STRIP(CHAR(MONTH)), 2) || '-01')
```

Then you can...

```
select int2month(month) || '-' || strip(char(year)) from test

1                                     
--------------------------------------------------
May-2011                                                          
June-2011                                                         
December-2012
```

If you want a 3 char month then change last last on function to...

```
RETURN LEFT(MONTHNAME('2000-' || RIGHT('0' || STRIP(CHAR(MONTH)), 2) || '-01'), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is pretty old, but there's a way that is a lot simpler than any of the options listed here (in my opinion) -- a combination of some date math and the [`VARCHAR_FORMAR()`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html) function:

```
SELECT 
    VARCHAR_FORMAT(
         DATE('0001-01-01') + (month_col - 1) MONTH + (year_col - 1) YEAR
        ,'Month-YYYY'
    )
FROM your_table
```