# How to get string value for a month DB2

Tags: db2

```
select MONTH (birth_date) ...
....
..
```

However this gives numeric values.

I need `Jan , Sep ...`

How can I do this ? `Case birth_date when 1 then 'jan' when 2 then ...` is too long

Any other efficient ways ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values of that column are not a time stamp you will have to do a [CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037982/db2-date-conversion). However, if it is a timestamp than maybe you can use the [MONTHNAME function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000831.html)

Comment: MONTHNAME works with date: expression
    An expression that returns a value of one of the following built-in data types: a DATE, TIMESTAMP, or a valid character string representation of a date or timestamp that is not a CLOB.

Answer (score 3):

You use several functions that provide the information that you need:

- VARCHAR_FORMAT - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html
- SUBSTR - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html
- LCASE - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052924.html

Example

```
Select LCASE(SUBSTR(VARCHAR_FORMAT(birth_date,'Month'),1,4))
From ...
```

This works with Timestamp or date